# OpenGL Back Face Texture

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I got a game tile on witch I want to simulate a flip animation.

So I'm using glRotatef(angle, 0, 1, 0) on my Tile to simulate a flip animation starting from 180 deg angle, in this way my tile start backflipped and show me the backface. Everything is fine but the problem is that when my tile start backflipped i don't want to see the flipped texture.

The result I would like to see is a black color (provided by vertex color) or a different texture for the back Face and the game texture for the front Face.
More simply i would like to build a sort of Game Card.

Anyone can suggest me a way to solve my problem?

Comment: so you want to have a black colour on the backface while flipping, and finally when its flipped you want to have another texture displayed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable backface culling (`glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)`), draw two quads back-to-back each with it's own texture.

Comment: I didn't thought it ... I tried to enable GL_CULL_FACE but the result was a "transparent" quad for backface and the right texture for the frontface. Now I'll try to add a second quad for the backface

Comment: @Gabriele: Just make sure that when the second quad faces the screen it's vertices are winding counterclockwise projected to screen space.